# Have python find and evaluate all decorated functions in codebase

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to have functions in my code base that are callable by a unique identifier, for this I created a decorator that registers the function

```
global FUNCTION_REGISTRY
FUNCTION_REGISTRY = {}

class FunctionAlreadyRegistered(Exception):
    pass

def register_function(function_identifier, function):
    global FUNCTION_REGISTRY

    if function_identifier not in FUNCTION_REGISTRY:
        FUNCTION_REGISTRY[function_identifier] = function
    else:
        raise FunctionAlreadyRegistered

def call_registered_function(function_identifier, *args, **kwargs):
    global FUNCTION_REGISTRY
    if function_identifier in FUNCTION_REGISTRY:
        FUNCTION_REGISTRY[function_identifier](*args, **kwargs)

class EventHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, identifier):
        self.identifier = identifier

    def __call__(self, original_func):
        decorator_self = self

        def wrappee(*args, **kwargs):
            original_func(*args, **kwargs)

        print "REGISTER FUNCTION", decorator_self.identifier
        register_function(decorator_self.identifier, wrappee)
        return wrappee
```

and then I apply this decorator like this

```
@EventHandler(identifier="something.task-created-handler")
def task_created_event_handler(pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
   pass
```

this allows me to easily do the following

```
call_registered_function("something.task-created-handler",argument="value")
```

however this decorator is only evaluated when some other file imports this file intentionally, I'd like to evaluate all this decorator through my codebase to register all identified functions

Is there a way to get python to evaluate all this decorators when the runtime starts in a seamless way?

Comment: Something like importing all modules in `__init__.py` so that everything is evaluated? Otherwise, I don't quite see how you can do this. A module (regardless of whether there are functions or decorators or classes in it) is only evaluated when the module is imported.

Comment: @nir0s if I do this, this causes django to throw this exceptions `raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

Comment: That's probably because you can only import certain things under certain conditions. I'm not saying that you can. I'm saying that if you can, that would be a way to do it. If there are modules that require context, it's not possible to evaluate them without running the code. That's how python works.

Comment: @nir0s what I ended up doing was close to your solution, using the `__init__` files, but conditionally importing it at the `app` level on django using the `ready` method with a custom config, that did the trick!

Comment: Great! I think we should formulate an answer then for the benefit of all

Comment: You really should not be using global variables but instead have the `EventHandler` class handle everything. At the end of the module create an instance like `handler = EventHandler() # default handler` which you can use like `from path.to.lib import handler` in all your files and decorate functions with `@handler.wrap`. You can always access the registered functions from the default handler instance.